# remove defaut icon from bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to use a Font Awesome arrow instead of the default Bootstrap arrow for the dropdown menu link. I've added the Font Awesome arrow and it looks the way I want (on the left), but still there is the default Bootstrap arrow on the right. How can I get rid of it? I can't say I've tried anything yet as I keep checking and I don't find anything to be removed anywhere.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown drop-li">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down arrow-down"></i>O Festiwalu <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu drop-one">
      <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Something</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is how it looks: http://postimg.org/image/id3jbf27x/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not deleting `<b class="caret"></b>`?

If you are using Firefox, you can press `STRG + I` (I for Inspection) to inspect your html Code and see why something is here (Click on the Element in the Main Page) or even not here (Look at the CSS in the right bottom and select via the left bottom).

Comment: That was so simple, thank you! I went all over the Bootstrap css trying to determine how is that glyph even there and I haven't paid attention to the obvious. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can (a couple of minutes for a newbie).